# Arch QEMU VM ssh anomalies

Tags: arch-linux, virtual-machine, qemu, sshd

I have setup an Arch VM with no-password, public/private key ssh logins. All of my initial tests have worked, including scp. I've verified that the ssh server is starting automatically.

Here's the problem: if I start the VM via the terminal (with `virsh start Arch`), I cannot ssh/scp to it, no matter how long I wait (getting `ssh: connect to host qemu-arch port 22: Connection refused` error). However, if I login via the `virt-manager` GUI, the scp/ssh commands begin to work again, almost as if I needed to jumpstart the system. I've checked the system logs and nothing stands out as to why this is happening. Also, none of my other VMs (Linux and Windows) experience this issue.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56173968/why-is-ssh-blocked-before-first-console-login), I was able to get ssh to work by adding a /dev/urandom device via `virt-manager`. What's weird is that my other Linux VMs all work, and most did not have the /dev/urandom device.